# LSI 9211-8i error: `mpt2sas_cm0: mpt3sas_scsih_issue_tm: timeout`, filesystem disappears. Hardware issue?

Tags: filesystems, raid, hardware-failure

Every few days on my DL380 G6, I get the following error:

`mpt2sas_cm0: mpt3sas_scsih_issue_tm: timeout`

And the filesystem completely dies, spewing `ext4_find_entry` errors or similar whenever a process tries to access the disk, as if the entire filesystem is read only. SSH fails to connect, nothing responds. If I have a shell session open, it's as if *all files on the root partition* disappear.

I'm using an LSI 9211-8i connected through SAS to an SSD (not the issue; I've tried two), and Ubuntu 18.04 with Linux 4.15.

Before I try buying another RAID card, does this seem like a hardware issue?

Answer (score 0):

LSI 9211-8i HBAs are simple and reliable especially if you run IT firmware without BIOS ROM.

Since there isn't enough info to answer your question, I propose you proceed with standard diagnostic flow... So question is is it HBA or SSD ?

- does firmware runs (heartbeat LED blinks ? ) when you turn on your PC
- if you have a BIOS ROM on it, do you see the card's ROM messages during POST.
- if yes to can you get into the BIOS ? can you see your HDD ?
- if you use RAID firmware then obviously check virtual drives

At this point you would have some idea where the real issue is.

PS - These HBAs are cheap and worth of every cent. You can find a cheap one on ebay as spare one so you never worry if it dies. I have few ones in use, and few as spare; they are a life saver when it comes flashing expanders or low level formatting SSDs, changing sector size. Spare one is a must either way.